# Problem in understanding in the derivation of torsion acting on a circular shaft fixed at one end

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

[image]

My doubt is how Arc(ab) = L $\gamma$. Arc (ab) = R$\theta$ makes sense as that's the arc of that circle.

Comment: Because $\gamma$ is a small angle.

Answer (score 1):

If the angle $\gamma$ is small we can approximate the arc $AB$ as a straight line:

[image: length of AB]

Then the length $AB$ is simply:

$$ AB = L\tan\gamma $$

Since $\gamma$ is small $\tan\gamma\approx\gamma$ and the equation becomes:

$$ AB \approx L\gamma $$